# How do I stack a fixed positioned element in front of a statically positioned element?

Tags: javascript, css

z-index won't work because they're (as I understand it) in different stacking contexts.  I don't mind using javascript or jquery to do it, I just can't figure out how to get a statically positioned element in front of a fixed positioned element.

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-positioned element, it has to be either static, fixed, relative or absolute.

Comment: Sorry. Static positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make your statically positioned element `position: relative;` (which wont move it anywhere) and then you can use `z-index` to put it where you want.

Comment: This worked. I had to rewrite some other code that was fixing elements relative to the statically positioned object, but it wound up working.

Comment: When something is relatively positioned, it will be in the same place as it would have been in the 'normal flow' aka 'statically positioned' but you can adjust it using left: x; right: x; etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a stacking context in (probably) the parent elements. Simply setting `position:relative` will enable stacking (`z-index` *requires* positioning) - whereas an element with the default `position:static` can not be stacked.

Trace your elements up the tree and find where two siblings can be layered, give them a relative position and a z-index;

Javascript wont be useful here.